# change google map with changing city name in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have included the city specific latitude, longitude in a city.js file and i am getting the content of the city from that file.

Now, i want to pass that information into my javaScript code to change the map with the change in city name.

I have tried something like this but didn't get success-----

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.get('City.js', function(data){
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
            var lat = jsonObject[1].latitude;
            var lng = jsonObject[1].longitude;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            $("#City").change(function () {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true
                });
            });
     });
```

here city.js is a java script file.The content of the java script file is---

```
   var jsonObject = [{ "CityId": "1", "CityName": "Faridabaad", "latitude":  "28.4211", "longitude": "77.3078" },
                     { "CityId": "2", "CityName": "Greater Noida", "latitude": "28.4962", "longitude": "77.5360" }];
```

My dropdown list which changes locality name as the city name changes is working fine.Now, i only want is to change google map as the city name changes in the dropdown list----My working code is like this----

```
           $("#City").change(function () {
            $("#Locality").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadLocalities","Project")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#City").val() },
                success: function (localities) {
                    $.each(localities, function (i, locality) {
                        $("#Locality").append('<option value="' + locality.Value + '">' +
                             locality.Text + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retreive Locality.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
     });
```

My javaScript code for loading google map is as----

```
          var map;

          function initialize() {
           var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.713956, 77.006653);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        draggable: true,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Project location"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {


        //document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
        //document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
        document.getElementById("Geolongitude").value = event.latLng.lng();
        document.getElementById("Geolatitude").value = event.latLng.lat();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        map.setZoom(9);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

My form are having two dropdown list like this---

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
               {
                  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter the Project Details</legend>
           <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
            </div>
           <div class="editor-field">

            @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("City")){
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, ViewData["City"] as    List<SelectListItem>,   new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1"})  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
            }
      </div>

                      <div class="editor-label">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Locality)
                         </div>
                      <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Locality", new SelectList(string.Empty,"Value","Text"),"Please Select a locality", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1" })
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sorry, But i have provided the minimal code. In the first code snippets, i have provided code where i am getting error. In second code snippet, minimum information is provided to make everyone aware of the situation.  In the last code snippet, i have provided the dropdown list where i want to change google map as the drop down list selection changes---@geocodezip

Comment: There is no HTML/CSS or samples of data for the second function to reproduce your issue (or a map for that matter).  You probably don't need AJAX for a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set the map center do it;

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.793949,-52.348643),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

// Save map as global variable.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

On your change City function;

```
// Catch center;
center = map.getCenter();

// .. insert your code here to change center object lat/long
// center.lat = -50.00 ( I do not remember the atribute name )


map.setCenter(center);
```

Comment: @Cairo henrique Thanks for the help and reminding me that i have to write code on city change function----lol

Comment: I still didn't get any satisfactory answer from any member of this community. .waiting for someone to help me out as I am new to java script , jquery and ajax